# Name for space which is countable union of compact sets

Tags: terminology

Is there a name for a (topological) space which is the countable union of compact sets.

For example $\mathbb{R}^N = \bigcup_{j\in\mathbb{N}} j \,B_{\mathbb{R^N}}$.

Comment: $\sigma$-compact.

Comment: Thanks! Should I delte this question again, because it seems kind of trivial?